# How do I remove nested elements within json data to extract the subnested data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have data that I ingest from an API that outputs json data in the below format. If you notice, there's a nest element called "user". This nested element is creating duplicate values when I export it to another source system. **My goal is to extract the data (id, first_name,etc.) from the user element and keep the data within the 'user' element.**

Here is the raw json format that the API produces:

```
[{
"enrollment_id": 12,
"content_type": "sample",
"user": {
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Sarah",
"last_name": "Kis",
"email": "s_kis@aol.com"
},
"campaign_name": "camp1",
"policy_acknowledged": false
    },
"enrollment_id": 13,
"content_type": "samplee",
"user": {
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Sarahe",
"last_name": "Kiss",
"email": "s_kiss@aol.com"
},
"campaign_name": "camp2",
"policy_acknowledged": false
}]
```

**Here is my desired output or something similar:**

```
 [{
"enrollment_id": 12,
"content_type": "sample",
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Sarah",
"last_name": "Kis",
"email": "s_kis@aol.com",
"campaign_name": "camp1",
"policy_acknowledged": false
},"enrollment_id": 13,
"content_type": "samplee",
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Sarahe",
"last_name": "Kiss",
"email": "s_kiss@aol.com",
"campaign_name": "camp2",
"policy_acknowledged": false
}]
```

**Notice how the data within the 'user' element has now been extracted into the json file. I know this is probably a easy quick fix but I have spent hours trying to figure this out but to no avail. **

Here is the code that I have so far (see below). Something to note is that this REMOVES the user element from the json file completely. I want to keep the data within the element though.

```
 path1 = '/Users/t1_{0}.json'
 path2 = '/Users/t2_{0}.json'
    
 with open(path1, 'r') as the_list:
        data = json.load(the_list)
    
 for element in data:
        element.pop('user', None)
    
  with open(path2, 'w') as the_list:
        data = json.dump(data, the_list)
```

Here is my full code for reference:

```
def load_pst_rec_data(proxy=my_proxy, api_header=api_header,
                      url=rec_url, path=my_path):

    all_psts = ['2011676', '2345729']  # List of items i am filtering in the subsequent data
    the_list = []
    s = requests.Session()  # Create API session
    s.proxies = my_proxy

    for obj in all_psts:  # Loop through the items inside the all_pst variable
        for i in range(1, 10000000):  # Due to pagination of the API, we have to loops through each page to collect data
            try:
                response = requests_retry_session(session=s). \
                    get(url + '{0}/recipients?page={1}&per_page=500'.format(obj, i), headers=api_header,
                        verify=False)  # Connect to the API
                resp = response.json()
            except Exception as e:
                print('It failed :(', e.__class__.__name__)
            else:
                print('It eventually worked', response.status_code)
                if resp:  # Consider using while resp: ______
                    the_list.extend(resp)  # Loop through results and add it to a list
                elif not resp:
                    last_page = str(i)  # Get the last page
                    print("Should stop and go to next object")
                    break
            finally:
                print('process done!')

    # This section attempts to load the data collected to a json file
    try:
        print('Beginning Json process')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        path1 = '/Users/t1_{0}.json'
        path2 = '/Users/t2_{0}.json'

        with open(path1, 'r') as the_list:
            data = json.load(the_list)

        for element in data:
            element.pop('user', None)

        with open(path2, 'w') as the_list:
            data = json.dump(data, the_list)
```

Comment: Instead of trying to edit the existing data structure, why not just make a new (flattened) one with just the data you want to propagate?

Comment: How would that look like in code?

Comment: `flat_dict = {k: old_dict[k] for k in list_of_keys_you_want}; result = {**flat_dict, **old_dict['user']}; return json.dumps(result)` actually kirk strauser's answer is the same thing but better.

Comment: Where do I put that code at within my script?

Answer (score 2):

Is that data structure fixed? Like you're trying to solve this one specific problem and don't need a more flexible solution?

```
data = {
    "enrollment_id": 12,
    "content_type": "sample",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Sarah",
        "last_name": "Kis",
        "email": "s_kis@aol.com"
    },
    "campaign_name": "camp1",
    "policy_acknowledged": False
}

user_info = data.pop("user")
data.update(user_info)
```

Comment: The solution can be flexible. As long as when I put it into splunk, there is no duplicates or unflattened values

Answer (score 1):

```
# an example list
data = [
    {"a": 1, "x": { "b": 2, "c": 3 }},
    {"a": 4, "x": { "b": 5, "c": 6 }},
]

# if you want to modify it in-place (without creating a new list)
for element in data:
    # pop removes the item and returns it to you
    # if it doesn't exist, it returns None by default, but here I've asked
    # it to return an empty dictionary
    x = element.pop("x", {})
    # update the parent dictionary with all the contents of x
    element.update(x)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
```

In your case, replace "x" with "user".

Take a look at [dictionary.pop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) and [dictionary.update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_nested(d):
    dd ={}
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i],(dict)):
            key = d[i]
            dd.update({k:d[i][k] for k in d[i]})
        else:
            dd[i] = d[i]
    return dd
```

Comment: Could you tie that in with the code i provided, pleas?

Comment: First put that defination in your code and then in the loop before dumping file in path2, call that function as element = remove_nested(element) instead of element.pop('user', None).

Answer (score 0):

if you use pandas to handle it, maybe not so efficient, but you can get the code easier to read.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = '''
[{
    "enrollment_id": 12,
    "content_type": "sample",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Sarah",
        "last_name": "Kis",
        "email": "s_kis@aol.com"
    },
    "campaign_name": "camp1",
    "policy_acknowledged": false
}, {
    "enrollment_id": 13,
    "content_type": "samplee",
    "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Sarahe",
        "last_name": "Kiss",
        "email": "s_kiss@aol.com"
    },
    "campaign_name": "camp2",
    "policy_acknowledged": false
}]
'''
data = json.loads(data)

# if the json format is fix
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
# save user.id, user.first_name... as the key
data_new = df.to_json(orient='records') 


# strip 'user.'
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(r'user\.').str[-1]
# if you want the type data2 is list, not str, use df.to_dict instead
data2 = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

---

output:

```
data_new (type: str)

[
  {
    "enrollment_id": 12,
    "content_type": "sample",
    "campaign_name": "camp1",
    "policy_acknowledged": false,
    "user.id": 1,
    "user.first_name": "Sarah",
    "user.last_name": "Kis",
    "user.email": "s_kis@aol.com"
  },
  {
    "enrollment_id": 13,
    "content_type": "samplee",
    "campaign_name": "camp2",
    "policy_acknowledged": false,
    "user.id": 2,
    "user.first_name": "Sarahe",
    "user.last_name": "Kiss",
    "user.email": "s_kiss@aol.com"
  }
]


data2 (type: list)

[{'enrollment_id': 12,
  'content_type': 'sample',
  'campaign_name': 'camp1',
  'policy_acknowledged': False,
  'id': 1,
  'first_name': 'Sarah',
  'last_name': 'Kis',
  'email': 's_kis@aol.com'},
 {'enrollment_id': 13,
  'content_type': 'samplee',
  'campaign_name': 'camp2',
  'policy_acknowledged': False,
  'id': 2,
  'first_name': 'Sarahe',
  'last_name': 'Kiss',
  'email': 's_kiss@aol.com'}]
```